# GestureOverlayView not working

Tags: android, view, gesture, gesture-recognition, ontouchlistener

I am kind of puzzeld right now :

I created 4 gestures using the Gesturebuilder
1 Gesture is a swipe pointing up
2 Gesture is a swipe pointing down
3 Gesture is a swipe pointing left
4 Gesture is a swipe pointing right

but when I try to make a gesture on the running app
only left and right is recognized but also it seams like up and down are the same like left and right
because the method gives me the getsures as a toat

the toast for swiping left shows : up,left

I am also using a custom view in my activity and a OntouchListener but I can't get it to work

Activity :

```
public class RunActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnGesturePerformedListener {

    static int width;
    static int height;

    static boolean reset=false;


    draw d;


    //jump
    private GestureLibrary gestureLib;


private static Context mContext;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        d = new draw(this);
        d.setOnTouchListener(this);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mContext = this;


        //get screen size
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();


        width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
        height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated


        //Jump
        GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        View inflate = d;
        gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
        gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
        gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!gestureLib.load()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(gestureOverlayView);

        //setContentView(d);
    }
    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("touch","touched");

        if (draw.end == true)
        {
        reset=true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
        for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `onTouch()` method, or at least chain to the superclass instead of simply returning `false`, and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried that but the up/down gesture still isn't recognized

Comment: this seems to be the same issue with my gesture implementation. Any ideas ?